# How can I give a group of controls a single tooltip, and have it appear smoothly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, tooltip

I have a grid of controls, where each editable control (checkbox, combobox, etc.) has an associated label. I want to share a tooltip between the label and its control.

Now this is something that I have accomplished by using [BindableToolTips](http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/07/17/elementname-binding-in-tooltips-borrowing-a-namescope/): I simply define the ToolTip in my XAML resources, and then set the same ToolTip object individually on the label and the control.

Code:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"
           ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ExampleControl}"
           Utilities:ToolTipServiceExtended.BindableToolTip="{StaticResource ExampleControlTT}"
           Text="Example label:" />
<CheckBox Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="1"
          x:Name="ExampleControl"
          Utilities:ToolTipServiceExtended.BindableToolTip="{StaticResource ExampleControlTT}"
          Content="Example" />
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't make it appear smoothly... When the mouse is moved from the label to the control, or from the control to the label, the tooltip disappears and reopens, appearing to flicker. This occurs even when there is no gap between the label and control, and does not look good. This obviously occurs because they are two separate tooltips.

I would like to somehow group the label and its associated control, and have the tooltip appear on that single group; this way, it can appear fluidly and not flicker when the mouse is moved between the two. Unfortunately, I am struggling to do this. Here are some things I have tried...

**Empty TextBlock with the tooltip applied and ColumnSpan=2.**

Unfortunately, this prevents the control from receiving mouse clicks, as the TextBlock covers it up invisibly. I have tried setting IsHitTestVisible to false, but then that prevents it from receiving mouse over events, which stops the tooltip appearing at all. If I could just make it so that the mouse clicks through the empty TextBlock, but the TextBlock still gets mouse over events, then it would be perfect.

Code:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Text="Example label:" />
<CheckBox Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="1"
          x:Name="ExampleControl"
          Content="Example" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ExampleControl}"
             Utilities:ToolTipServiceExtended.BindableToolTip="{StaticResource ExampleControlTT}" />
```

**Nested grid specifically for the one label and one control.**

This method seems to work: the tooltip appears whenever the mouse is anywhere over the inner grid, and mouse events are still successfully passed to the control. Unfortunately, this has three problems:

1. It is very messy, as I will need many nested grids for every label/control combination.
2. The "Auto" column widths no longer take into account the widths of other controls in the outer grid, because this is of course a separate grid.
3. It seems to ignore the tooltip placement settings, which are Placement=Right and with PlacementTarget being the specific control. Instead, the tooltip appears underneath the inner grid.

If the last two problems could be fixed, then this would be an acceptable solution.

Code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ExampleControl}"
             Utilities:ToolTipServiceExtended.BindableToolTip="{StaticResource ExampleControlTT}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Text="Example label:" />
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="1"
              x:Name="ExampleControl"
              Content="Example" />

</Grid>
```

Does anybody have any ideas for a good solution to this problem? I simply want my tooltips to appear over both the label and the associated control as though they are one element, without flickering when the mouse is moved between them all. That's all.

Comment: I generally don't like nested grids and find that layout is smoother with a combination of DockPanels and StackPanels.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the controls in a content presenter and attach the tooltip to that.

```xml
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ContentPresenter ToolTip="Blah">
        <ContentPresenter.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Example label:"/>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ExampleControl" Content="Example" />
            </Grid>
        </ContentPresenter.Content>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But I'm unsure as to how this is different from the "Nested grid specifically for the one label and one control" solution mentioned in my question post. This will still require a grid (for my layout) for every label/control combination, so what does the added ContentPresenter achieve? It will still have the same problems (auto column width not shared between grids, etc.), won't it? Thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: @Chris - It was my understanding that the grid binding didn't work properly. I left the grid in place for clarity/continuity, but you can replace the grid with whatever you need, like a stack panel, or dock panel. I'm not sure I can address your layout issues without more context.